# Bound checkbox state doesn't fire OnPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I've got a list of checkboxes bound like this.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllThings}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"
                IsChecked="{Binding Active,Mode=TwoWay}"
                Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked"
                Unchecked="ToggleButton_OnUnchecked"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The binding works one-way because I can see that the boxes are checked/unchecked based on my settings from the beginning. I was expecting checking a box to update the underlying viewmodel but it doesn't happen. The breakpoint set on the *OnPropertyChanged* doesn't get hit. I suspect that it's got to do with the fact that I'm changing a property **inside** the observed property but due to ignorance I'm not sure.

```
class Presenter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private IEnumerable<Something> _allThings;
  public IEnumerable<Something> AllThings
  {
    get { return _allThings; }
    set
    {
      _allThings = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("AllThings");
    }
  }

  public Presenter()
  {
    _allThings = DataAccessor.GetThings();
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(
    [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
  {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

What can I be missing here?

As far I can see I'm doing **precisely** [as this guy suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13734174/1525840). Obviously I'm missing something but it's beyond me what...

## edit

As per request from @Clemens, I also implemented the interface in the *Soomething* class.

```
public class Something :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public bool Active { get; set; }

  public override String ToString()
  {
    return Name;
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(
    [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

Comment: class `Something` would also have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @Clemens Oh, because it's a **two**-way, right? Still, I'd expect the method *OnPropertyChanged* to be invoked anyway (if not when clicking in the checkbox, at least when changing the value of the *bool* property *Active*, which can be done from the watch)... Sadly, It didn't worked out (yet). I've inherited and implemented the equivalent in the *Something* class too. No cookies hit far...

Comment: No, not because it's two-way. The interface has to be implemented by the class that declares the properties (about which it wants to send property change notifications). As the properties `Name` and `Active` are declared by class `Something`, that class has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @Clemens I can't stop the feeling that the problems depends on the fact that I'm managing the **property's** change but should be handling the change of the **property's property**. Am I totally off?

Comment: "property's property" just makes no sense at all. It's called the property's *value*, and that is what should be notified about when it changes. I'd still recommend to get a book about WPF, take a few days to read up on all those basics, and then continue with whatever you're doing. Adam Nathan's *WPF Unleashed* would be a perfect start.

Comment: @Clemens If the property is a class then its value can have properties...

Comment: Or perhaps get a C# book first. The type of a property can of course be a class, which again may have properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

class `Something` must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. This means that besides writing

```
public class Something : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

it also has to actually raise the `PropertyChanged` event when property values change, e.g.:

```
private string name;
public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set
    {
        name = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tool a liberty to correct to better fit the question (checkboxes have seldom editable **names**). Other than that, yupp, that was the issue.